# Update table data using two joins in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 3 tables, and they are linked to each other. How can I upload data from table3 to table 1?

I tried this code:

```
UPDATE table1
SET t1.new_column = t3.old_data
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.some_key = t2.some_key
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.some_key2 = t3.some_key2;
```

But it doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: 1) Q: What is your database? Q: Are you getting any syntax errors or warnings? 2) Please clarify exactly "what isn't working". SUGGESTION: 3) For debugging purposes, change your "UPDATE/SET" to a simple "SELECT", and make sure your query is correct.  In particular, make sure the "SELECT" returns at least one row.

Comment: Are you sure the row set isn't empty after your joins, because the query looks properly structured. Try a select on those joins and make sure. Also if you're using aliases you should keep using them, in an update from select you `UPDATE t1 SET...`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and your help!

Comment: No, they are full with data and with SELECT it works

Comment: I work in PLSQL and it says that SQL command not properly ended.

Comment: I'm not sure Oracle supports that UPDATE FROM syntax. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/UPDATE.html#GUID-027A462D-379D-4E35-8611-410F3AC8FDA5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating a join in Oracle is done using the join first and then the update. Thus the syntax looks like:

```
UPDATE (
select t1.new_column , t3.old_data
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.some_key = t2.some_key
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.some_key2 = t3.some_key2
)
set new_column = old_data
```

The join must result in what is called "key preserved" data, ie, the rows that come back from the query must map one to one with the rows in the target table, otherwise you'll get an error.

For this reason, people often choose to rewrite their update as a MERGE statement.